# Scriptish GM_getResourceText doesn't work

Tags: greasemonkey, scriptish

This works on Greasemonkey, but I don't know why it doesn't work on Scriptish:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        myscript
// @namespace   xxx
// @include     http://*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @resource    resourceName http://xxx.xxx/style.css
// ==/UserScript==

alert(GM_getResourceText('resourceName'))
```

The css file is actually downloaded, and console log says `[myscript] not defined`.

Comment: Consider [filing a bug report for Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/issues).

Answer (score 0):

This has come up since Firefox update to version 30. Try to "enable @grant" in the settings of Scriptish. If you don't find this setting in your Scriptish options dialog, go to URL `about:config` and find the key `extensions.scriptish.enableScriptGrant`. If that doesn't work, go to scriptish download page and list all available versions. Version 0.1.12 works well with Firefox 30. Official latest version is 0.1.11.